# Django send_mail returns SMTPConnectError

Tags: python, django, email, smtplib

I am trying to send an email using Django send_email, smtp and gmail. However, the code returns SMTPConnectError (-1, b")

My settings.py file:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'mygmailid'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'mygmailid'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mygmailid'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'myPassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

My views.py file:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from smtplib import SMTPConnectError
#rest of the code in between
....
try:
   send_mail('testmail', 'test content', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['arkaghosh024@gmail.com', fail_silently=False])
except SMTPConnectError as e:
   return HttpResponse(e)
```

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.2-  py3.4.egg\django\core\mail\__
init__.py", line 62, in send_mail
return mail.send()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.2- py3.4.egg\django\core\mail\me
ssage.py", line 303, in send
return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg\django\core\mail\ba
ckends\smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
new_conn_created = self.open()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg\django\core\mail\ba
ckends\smtp.py", line 58, in open
self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params
)
File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 244, in __init__
raise SMTPConnectError(code, msg)
smtplib.SMTPConnectError: (-1, b")
```

When I change the EMAIL_BACKEND to:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

it works fine. Also, it doesn't show the error when I use dummy backend.

I have tried using SSL instead of TLS, allowed less secure apps in gmail, turned off firewall and also tried other stackoverflow posts related to sending email via django but nothing worked. I don't know what the error is. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might need to unlock Captcha to enable Django to send email for you:
https://accounts.google.com/displayunlockcaptcha

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Best of luck to you! (:

Answer (score 0):

Gmail account need this:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your-username@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your-password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

2. then test its works by:

python manage.py shell

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('testEmail', 'hi', 'Youremail@email.com', ['Emailtest@email.com'])
```

If you're not using a gmail account and still getting problems then just try add the EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD to what you have. If you still have issues maybe your network is blocking you. Firewalls on your OS or router.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried all these. The problem has been resolved now. It had something to do our institute network. I didn't post the solution because it was a very institute specific issue.